# You may not have permission to create projects in this organisation

Tags: android, api, maps, key

Any idea how to solve this error 
:You may not have permission to create projects in this organisation. Contact your Google Apps account admin to verify that you have the Project Creator role.

Getting the error while wanting to get google maps api key to android app

Comment: this does not relate to programming. It is only related to some permissions on google developer console web site

Comment: Solved it just  if you are creating your project  you need to set No organization than it will not ask you anything !

Answer (score 0):

The owner of your account has not give you access to crate project. You need to told you account owner to get access to create project. For more details you can check this link. [For more details you can check this link](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/control-api-access)